# javascript functions and this keyword, context

Tags: javascript, keyword

Here is the code

```
obj = {
    a: 'some value';
    m: function(){
        alert(this.a);
    }
}

obj.m();
```

The result is `'some value'`.

I heard that this keyword refers to the owner of the function with is `obj`.
now the question is that the owner of the function in above code is `obj` so why is it important to use this keyword when the function has the owner the code above should
be working in the following way

```
obj = {
    a: 'some value';
    m: function(){
        alert(a);
    }
}

obj.m();
```

Which does not work I know but why?

Comment: Functions don't really have owners.

Comment: There's no special relationship between a function and an object. An object can reference a function, but then several objects can reference the same function at the same time. A function itself is just another type of native object, like an Array for example.

Answer (score 6):

`a` is not available in the scope of the function `m`.

`a` is a property of object `obj` and available only as `obj.a` or `this.a` within the context of `obj`.

Since `obj.m()` executes `m` in the context of `a`, you can access `a` using `this.a` inside function `m`.

In JavaScript, use of `this` is mandatory.

In other languages like Java or C++, use of `this` is optional. `x` automatically resolves to `this.x` if there's no local variable in Java / C++, but not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused when you say which object "owns" a function.  The "this" keyword is like a variable that points to whatever object *called* the function.

For example, you could write a function like this:

> function logThis(){ console.log(this.a); }

Now, you can make two different objects:

> var objOne = {
>   a: "I am a string stored at the key a", func: logThis }
>
> var objTwo = {
>   func: logThis
>   }

Notice that both objects have a key named "func" and that key is storing the "logThis" function.  That means that objOne.func  is the same as objTwo.func;  and they are both the same as logThis(){console.log(this.a)}

Now, if you invoke  objOne.func() it will log "I am a string stored at the key a" the object that called func is objOne, and that is the string that is stored at objOne.a

By contrast, if you invoke objTwo.func() you will get 'undefined'.  That is because objTwo is the object that called func, and objTwo does not have any property named a.